# grunt with java npm package not working

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I am using **grunt cli with npm**. I have some number of packages but there is one package named as *java* from npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/java). When *java* npm package is installed then grunt is not able to restart the node server on change in file.

So can you please let me know what is the issue of grunt with *java* npm package or how can I solve this?

I got this error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE" on change in any file.

Answer (score 1):

EADDINUSE means that port is already using by some other process. You need to chage the nodejs server port or kill the existing process which is running on the same port

Comment: Grunt auto restart the node server. But when i remove the java npm package then i didn't get this error. but when i installed this package then it throw the same error